# Parsing SOAP Response "By Hand"

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-namespaces

i have this soap response but my code isn't reading the GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResult children.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResponse xmlns="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0">
     <GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResult objectID="112199498" utility="xxxxx">
      <meterNo>112199498</meterNo> 
      <deviceID>112199498</deviceID> 
      <readingDate>2013-02-27T17:00:00.000Z</readingDate> 
      <posKWh>8406</posKWh> 
      <kW>15.508</kW> 
      <kWDateTime>2013-02-27T17:00:00.000Z</kWDateTime> 
      </GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResult>
     </GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code:

```
XmlDocument resultXml = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(resultXml.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
mgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0");
resultXml.LoadXml(soapResult);
XmlNodeList nodeList = resultXml.SelectNodes("//GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResult", mgr);
```

nodeList returns no nodes

Comment: Have you verified that your expected response is being returned from the server? You can do this through programs like SoapUI

Comment: The soap response is the raw string returned from the stream.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using "Add Service Reference"? There's very little reason to ever manipulate XML directly for SOAP.

Comment: i was going to ask you that, i kind of new to this soap deal.  I have a service that i created from the wsdl file.  It created the xxxRequest and xxxResponse methods but i don't know how to use them.  Do i write those to the stream as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
mgr.AddNamespace("multi", "http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0");
resultXml.LoadXml(soapResult);
XmlNodeList nodeList = resultXml.SelectNodes("//multi:GetLatestReadingByMeterNoResult", mgr);
```

Even when handling the default namespace, you need to use a prefix when using XPATH in code.

Comment: Glad to hear it. But why didn't you use "Add Service Reference" and be done with all this XML?